# grep - print the file name for the file grep currently is searching in

Tags: grep, macos

I don't have a problem with getting the name of the file where `grep` finds a match, however, something in the file hierarchy I am searching through takes forever (hours) to search (it is 1,4 GB data in 2000 files on an SSD so it shouldn't take that long) and I want to know what. Therefore, I would like some kind of *verbose* output where grep lists every file as it processes them.

How can this be done?

Using BSD grep on a Mac.

Comment: Not with `grep -r` directly. But with `find ... -exec ... {} +` you can do whatever you want.

Comment: If `grep -v` meant `--verbose`, this is what we might expect it to do (but `grep -v` means "invert the match"). This would be a worthy enhance for Gnu`grep --verbose`

Answer (score 5):

You have to call separate `grep` processes, together with printing the filename before starting to search. Of course this will be slower but in your case, as `grep` has a tiny starting load time, it will not disturb you, comparing to the current situation.

Using find and exec:

```bsh
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'printf "checking: %s\n" "$1"; grep pattern "$1"' sh {} \;
```

Or find and mass exec, to call one shell to loop

```bsh
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'for f do printf "checking: %s\n" "$f"; grep pattern "$f"; done' sh {} +
```

Or using find and xargs, with GNU zero separation for the file arguments:

```bsh
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sh -c 'for f do printf "checking: %s\n" "$f"; grep pattern "$f"; done'
```

---

By the way, as I see you are on macOS, please consider to install GNU software, for grep, sed, awk, etc.

Comment: `-d` is GNU specific and a lot less portable than `-0` (and would cause problems with filenames containing newlines (IIRC MacOS/X used to ship with such files in `/etc`)). Portably, you need to give at least one file to `find` (so here `find . ...` if you want to find files in the current working directory).

Comment: Well, yes, I omit the `-d` version, I thought `-d` was not GNU specific and added as an `xargs` alternative for mac (although not considering newlines, but for the case `-0` is not a choice). I hope `-exec` is fine for mac. Also I 'm surprised that macOS had newlines in default filenames, while having no default zero separation in their shell.

Comment: `-exec` is standard, `-0` is not but should be fine too. `-r` is less portable that `-0`, but FreeBSD supports it (it's the default there though which makes it not POSIX compliant, so I expect macOS' differs there as it's been certified as compliant).

Comment: In your first example, where do I enter the pattern ($1)? You seem to use a variable.

Comment: No, you don't. `$1` is the argument passed from `find -exec` into the shell `sh` we execute. Also this way we can do various things onto the argument, e.g. apply parameter expansion etc. You just have to define the parameters of your `find` command, the starting directory (`.` to mean the current one) what files you select, by type, name, etc.

Comment: The grep pattern is just the word 'pattern' in the above commands. Replace it with your pattern to search.

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh` (which I understand is now the default interactive shell on macOS), you could do:

```
for f (**/*(ND-.)) (set -x; grep pattern $f)
```

(where `set -x`, short for `set -o xtrace` prints the command that is being executed on stderr like in all POSIX shells, and `**/*(ND-.)` looks for all regular files after symlink resolution recursively, including hidden ones).

With GNU or FreeBSD `xargs` (so hopefully macOS' as well), you could do something similar with:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0tn1 grep pattern
```

(where the `-t` option does the equivalent of `xtrace`)

That doesn't look into symlinks to regular files though (GNU `find` has `-xtype f` for that, but not FreeBSD's). Whether `grep -r` itself looks into symlinks to regular files depends on the `grep` implementation and version, you may want to double-check with yours.

Those run one `grep` per file, so is going  to less efficient than a `grep -r`.

Another approach wouldbe to use a system call tracer like `strace`/`truss`/`dtruss`/`tusc` or whatever the equivalent is on your macOS and trace the `open()` or `openat()` or whatever system call `grep` uses to open the files.

On GNU/Linux, that would be:

```
strace -e open,openat grep -r pattern .
```

I don't know what the equivalent would be on macOS.

Comment: the `-r` for xargs failed. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @d-b, it avoids running the command if the input is empty. You can omit it in this case as it should be harmless here if `grep` is called without argument as it would then look in its stdin which would be empty (either `/dev/null` or the pipe depending on the `xargs` implementation).

Comment: Thank you. The result of this command was interesting, everything worked fine! There seems to be some issue with grep -ir itself that disappears when feeding grep with full paths instead. I therefore tried to remove -print0 since I am no longer interested in the log but then I got an error message `xargs: insufficient space for argument`?

Comment: Next, I removed xargs too, and just ran `find . -type f  | grep PATTERN` but then it finished very fast and no results were returned (when running the whole command as suggested in your post I get a few results). What am I missing here?

Comment: @d-b If you don't want the log, it's `-t` you want to remove, not `-print0`. If you remove `xargs`, you're grepping the output of `find`, not the contents of the files whose path is printed by `find`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done at a point in time with `lsof`, even on an already-running `grep`, though it won't continuously print the files as it goes.

First get the PID of the running `grep` process:

```
$ pgrep -l grep
21531 grep
```

Then list every open file of that process:

```
$ lsof -p 21531
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
grep    21531 izkata  cwd    DIR  253,1     4096 22020097 /var
grep    21531 izkata  rtd    DIR  253,1     4096        2 /
grep    21531 izkata  txt    REG  253,1   219456 22544390 /bin/grep
grep    21531 izkata  mem    REG  253,1  3004224 11805539 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
grep    21531 izkata  mem    REG  253,1   144976 29104688 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
grep    21531 izkata  mem    REG  253,1  2030544 29104673 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
grep    21531 izkata  mem    REG  253,1    14560 29104676 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
grep    21531 izkata  mem    REG  253,1   464824 29103098 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.3
grep    21531 izkata  mem    REG  253,1   170960 29104669 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
grep    21531 izkata  mem    REG  253,1    26376 12064533 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
grep    21531 izkata    0u   CHR  136,8      0t0       11 /dev/pts/8
grep    21531 izkata    1u   CHR  136,8      0t0       11 /dev/pts/8
grep    21531 izkata    2u   CHR  136,8      0t0       11 /dev/pts/8
grep    21531 izkata    3r   DIR  253,1     4096 22020408 /var/lib
grep    21531 izkata    4r   REG  253,1    35765 22156714 /var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd.md5sums
grep    21531 izkata    5r   DIR  253,1     4096 22020692 /var/lib/dpkg
grep    21531 izkata    6r   DIR  253,1   471040 22021003 /var/lib/dpkg/info
```

Most of it is just things `grep` needs to run, but those last 4 lines are directories and the file `grep` is currently reading (`/var/lib/dpkg/info/systemd.md5sums` in this example).

Comment: See also `lsof -ad3-999 -p 21531` to only list the files opened on fds above 2 to trim that output a bit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas FDS?

Comment: @d-b **f**ile **d**escriptor**s**

Comment: Your suggestion failed, grep was till open but it wasn't reading any file (other than its own files). It seems it "gave up" on something and was just hanging there.